# Prevent unintentional unfolding after application in Coq

Tags: coq

My notation has been unintentionally unfolded after application.
I don't want to call the tactic 'change' on the last line in text of the tiny example every time I am using modus ponens.
How to forbid Coq to unfold my Notation "( a '==' b )"?

```
Require Export Coq.Vectors.Vector.
Import VectorNotations.
Inductive Terms : Type :=
    FVC : nat -> Terms.
Definition Fo:=nat.
Context (axs0 : nat -> Type).
Context (Atom : Vector.t Terms 2 -> Fo).
Notation "( a '==' b )" := (Atom [a:Terms; b:Terms]).
Notation "( A --> B )" := (A + B).

Inductive GPR (axs : nat -> Type) (ctx:list nat) : nat -> Type :=
| MP (A B: Fo) : (GPR axs ctx A)->(GPR axs ctx (A --> B))
             ->(GPR axs ctx B).
Definition APR := GPR axs0.
Definition p2_23_a ctx (t:Terms) : APR ctx (t == t).
apply MP with (A:=(t == t)).
change (Atom [t; t]) with ((t==t)).  (* <-- I don't want to write this line. *)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
Notation "( a '==' b )" := (Atom [a:Terms; b:Terms]).
```

to

```
Notation "( a '==' b )" := (Atom [a; b]).
```

Type annotations appear in the AST, and get easily simplified away, so the notation rarely matches.